# Convert string to nested array

Tags: javascript, string-conversion

I have a string passed from server which was called with AJAX and I have to convert the string into a nested array which will be used to populate on PDF.

For example:

```
var tableData = "[{ name: 'Bartek', age: 34 },{ name: 'John', age: 27 },{ name:'Elizabeth', age: 30 }]";
```

and I need to convert into an array in JavaScript which will be like this:

```
var newTableData = [
    { name: 'Bartek', age: 34 },
    { name: 'John', age: 27 },
    { name: 'Elizabeth', age: 30 }
];
```

How can I do that?

Comment: @Carcigenicate **But that's not valid JSON**.

Comment: Please post your code you have tried so far, preferably in a working snippet demonstrating the problems you are currently having so we can see what might be the cause for them. Also, please also see [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and, if applicable, [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Actually, after looking at it, @ibrahimmahrir is correct, the properties are not encased in quotes.

Comment: @Carcigenicate There is no quotes surrounding keys and the quotes used to surround value are single `'` not double `"`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The outer `{}` are not needed as this is an array not an object.

Comment: sorry it's my first time using JavaScript so i got kinda confused...

Comment: @ArdiSugiarto Is the string exactly like that? How does the server generate it?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir actually i added the bracket manually from server so i can change it if i wanted to, but the point is to convert all those data into readable array on JavaScript.

Comment: @ArdiSugiarto If it was a [**valid JSON**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), it will be easy: just use `var newTableData = JSON.parse(tableData);`.

Comment: How the string get generated on the server side? Can you change that?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir the string was generated from database query and saved on string, then send back to client side using servlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the best solution would be to return a [valid JSON](http://www.json.org/) from the server and to parse it using `JSON.parse`.
You can use tools like https://jsonlint.com/ or [JSV](https://github.com/garycourt/JSV) to check that your JSON is valid.

If because of some "real world problem", your servers aren't JSON complaint, you can use a dirty parser like [dirty-json](https://github.com/RyanMarcus/dirty-json) or write your own [JSON parse](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json_parse.js).

`dirty-json` does not require object keys to be quoted, and can handle single-quoted value strings.

```
var dJSON = require('dirty-json');
dJSON.parse("{ test: 'this is a test'}").then(function (r) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
});

// output: {"test":"this is a test"}
```

Your last resort, while technically possible and the easiest to implement, is probably **your worst choice** because of it's [dangers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil). but it would work out of the box: `eval`.

```
eval(tableData);
// [ { name: 'Bartek', age: 34 },
//   { name: 'John', age: 27 },
//   { name: 'Elizabeth', age: 30 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

By slightly changing how you return the string from the server you can JSON.parse it

```
var dataString = '[{"name":"Bartek","age":34},{"name":"John","age":27},{"name":"Elizabeth","age":30}]';
var data = JSON.parse(dataString);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) method The completion value of evaluating the given code. If the completion value is empty, undefined is returned:

```js
var tableData = "[{ name: 'Bartek', age: 34 },{ name: 'John', age: 27 },{ name:'Elizabeth', age: 30 }]";

tableData = eval(tableData);
console.log(tableData[0]);
```